# Why is my POST method not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, http, http-post

When I send data in postman , I've got 200 status - success [[image: screen form postman1]

But when I try to send POST request to the same URL through Angular CLI , Ive got 400 error, which says MALFORMED_JSON

```
 const testData = {
    "address_1": "ddd",
    "contact_person_1": "ddd",
    "full_name": "dsad",
    "is_active": 2,
    "phone_no_1": "11111",
  }
return this.http.post(`${this.urlAdmin}branches/save`, testData).pipe(
  catchError((err) => {
      console.log('err' , err)
    return of(false);
  })
);
```

Here is screen below of my params in request in browser
[image]

Can somebody help please ?

Comment: check the token value

Comment: @Saran in Angular Im sending token in header , but even adding as a property , it is not working either

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this sequence when calling api from Angular:
this.http.post(baseUrl ,parameterModel, headers).pipe();

, as i see you need to add the header, your model, and make sure from the api path.